# Where is the directory of "configure -static ...." command

Tags: qt, configuration, qt5

i have a simple question(not for me!).in Qt 5.7, i want to set static building.the way is in "qt cmd" run the command `configure -static ....` and then ....
problem is i don't know the directory that  the command is defined in?!
my qt don't have dir like they said:
http://dimitris.apeiro.gr/2015/06/24/build-a-static-qt5-for-windows-by-compiling/
notice:
[my directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUB7n.png)

Comment: Did you compile Qt5 from source code?

Comment: It is in qtbase but there is also a shortcut to it in the main source directory.

Comment: unfortunately, there is no qtbase  folder in my qt DIR. i searched it.

Comment: You need the Qt sources, they can optionally be installed by the installer, or you can get them standalone, which I recommend, because the installer is really slow at unpacking them.